# Listen AccessibilityService events from a visible app without focus

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I'd like to get `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent)` triggered for a target app even if the app doesn't have the focus, for example I have another app with a dialog on top, so target app is still visible but doesn't have the focus.

I tried `List<AccessibilityWindowInfo> list = getWindows();` but this returned only app that has focus (dialog one) and also notifications.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I dont think we can get event of the any App without focus as per my research. I might be wrong.